# Why does 5 in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] return false?

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I really don't understand why both of the console.logs show me false when there's a 5 in the array

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const newArr = [];
  
  return 5 in arr2;
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(5 in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

I expected my function to return true

Comment: because `Object.keys([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` is `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']`

Comment: goto https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) tells you if the value on the left is a property **name** of the object on the right.

Since arrays are indexed from `0`, the array with 5 items in it has an item at positions 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 but not 5. It also has `length`, and various other properties.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr[5], 5 in arr);
console.log(arr[4], 4 in arr);
console.log(arr.length, 'length' in arr);
```

You might be looking for  [the `includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which tells you if the argument you passed is a value in the array.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr[4], arr.includes(5));
console.log(arr[3], arr.includes(4));
console.log(null, arr.includes('length'));
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's right, thanks! I expected the `in` to work the same way it does in python

Answer (score 1):

[The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) resolves to a boolean reepresenting whether an object has a property with a given key. In your example, you have constructed an array with elements at index 0-4, but nothing at index 5, so `5 in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` resolves to `false`.

If you want to check if an array contains a given value, you should use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr.includes(5)); // <- true
console.log(arr.includes(6)); // <- false

console.log(arr.indexOf(5)); // <- 4
console.log(arr.indexOf(6)); // <- -1, which means it's not there
```

For more complex checks, you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead. This is often needed when working with arrays of objects, which isn't what you're doing here.